# What is a good way to set Preprocessor values for an imported library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ant, static-libraries, c-preprocessor

I apologize if this is covered elsewhere, but I was unable to find the information readily. I am working with an extant library for my company that uses pre-processor directives to add and remove specialized capabilities. For example, we might have a IMPORT_OPENBLAS and IMPORT_SPEEX to indicate that the build needs to support use of the OpenBLAS and Speex libraries. We also have unit tests based off of the Google test framework, some of which need said pre-processor directives enabled to run, which statically link in our library. The two places where we typically run the unit tests are through Visual Studio (2008 if that makes a difference) and through Ant, which invokes vsbuild.exe to do the build.

So, long story short, I have been tasked with adding additional capabilities such as the above libraries. We have other projects that use our library and specifically don't want those capabilities turned on, in part due to issues with dependencies and in part because they don't want the additional complexity. My first impulse was to put the preprocessor directives into the unit test project, since it builds our library as a dependency anyhow, but that doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to flag things to indicate that a given pre-processor command needs to be turned on for compiling the dependent project?

Another alternative is to create new build targets for the unit tests which specifically set the right pre-processor flags, but I want to avoid that if possible because we already have 10 different build targets encompassing different linking methods, processor size, and debug versus release modes and one of my earlier tasks involved getting them all to work again since no one had compiled some of them for months since our primary release is based off of just two of those targets.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: It's more complicated than that. Not only do you need to compile *the core library* with the correct set of preprocessor directive `/DIMPORT_OPENBLAS` but you also need to compile *all client libraries* with the same set of preprocessor directives (at least, those that appear in headers of the core library). It means you may have to deliver the core library once *for each set of options* and go beyond the Debug/Release traditional split.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have a header file that includes those defines and include it in all the files in the project through the project properties. See the project properties -> Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Force Includes.

In other words, this file would be included in all the projects.